# Toolbar colors under API 21

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I want to add colors to my toolbar with an api under 21.

Here's my style.xml

```
<resources>
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and my app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CCC">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Like this : http://i.imgur.com/klAMznN.png

I can or not?

Comment: See also https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/AV2ooBWY1iy